# Returning the value before the function executed fully

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a function as shown below

```
func getRecipeArray(name:String) -> [String] {
    var query = PFQuery(className: name)
    query.selectKeys(["Recipe_Name"])
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            NSLog("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")
            for object in objects {
                var name: String = object.objectForKey("Recipe_Name")! as String
                self.dummyArray.append(name)

                }

        } else {

                NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)

            }
    }

    println(self.dummyArray.count)
    println(self.dummyArray)
    return self.dummyArray
}
```

It should return the array after retrieving the Recipe_name from the parse.
But its returning a value before only and then executing the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock function.

In console it printing the values as shown below

1
[]
2015-01-08 16:15:27.922 IndianFood[2268:67055] 
Successfully retrieved 2 scores.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You can't, you must use another closure.

Comment: query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock is asyncronous. unless you have a callback method it won't return the array

Comment: That's what you asked it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is an asynchronous method which is executed in a background thread. `self.dummyArray` will only be assigned after the background thread finished downloading and finding the data. But your function will return before the block finishes executing.

What you have to do is, do any operation you want to inside the `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` block, so that it will only execute after the background thread has completed its operation. Please note that any operation that requires UI update has to be done in the main thread. Dummy code follows.

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
     (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
       if error == nil {

         otherfunctions()

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
         {
             // UI updates like
             // label.text = object["name"]
         })
     }
}
```